# Could you give an example of a function (recursive or not) that finds if a binary search tree is too tall?

Tags: c, time-complexity

How can I find using C if a binary search tree is too tall relatively fast (most of the time)?

To be more specific , lets say I need to find if a tree has a height of at least 10 ,**without having to search the whole tree **most of the time****.

(This is possible because I expect most of the input to be binary search trees which have a heigh greater than 10.)

Comment: Welcome. This site is not a free code writing service. You need to come up with some code yourself. Read this: [ask]. Hint: start writing a simple search function and once that works, continue. Use a piece of paper and a pencil and draw a tree. BTW: you don't need recursion for this.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for the reply .I wasn't necessarily looking for code ,but rather an algorithm. I thought there would be a known algorithm regarding this problem ,but I might have been wrong. I chose C because it's a simple language and it's the one I use to study data structures.

Comment: *"I tried to look for examples online"* what where you looking for? examples of recursion? Of determining height of a tree? I would expect *thousands* of hits to both, so that *specifically* are you looking for that you weren't able to find or, perish the thought, engineer? Is maintaining tree height as a property of each node out of the realm of possibility? For cheap labor on management you get tree (and subtree) height in constant time.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the reply. I was looking for the fastest algorithm that can find if a tree is taller than a specific height. I couldn't find any such posts. I wasn't necessarily looking for a recursive function to do this ,I though if such an algorithm was common knowledge it would probably work using recursion ,because finding the height of a bst can easily be done recursively.

Comment: Without predetermined height as a property of a given node, iteration (be it by recursion or otherwise) of the tree is your *only* option. There is no magic box that spews an answer requiring N-work in O(1). You can stop iterating/recursing once you're precondition is satisfied, but until then you're SOL.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right ,if I add height as a property I could get the result in worst case O(1). I'll do that instead. Thanks.

Comment: Given the number of nodes in the tree you have an expectation about the (average) depth of a (succeeding/non succeding) search. You could add some heuristics, maybe even rebalance on the fly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a simple algorithm that returns `true` as soon as it's found a branch longer than 10.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _node
{
    int data;
    struct _node *l, *r;
}
node;

node *tree; // some tree
...

bool is_too_tall(node *node, int depth, int max_depth)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return false;
    if (depth > max_depth)
        return true;
    
    return is_too_tall(node->l, depth + 1, max_depth) 
        || is_too_tall(node->r, depth + 1, max_depth);
}

int main()
{
    if (is_too_tall(tree, 1, 10))
        puts("Tree is too tall");
}
```

I think [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) is the best option for this algorithm (as opposed to [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) because it is faster and simpler.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no preconditions about the structure of the tree, there's no other way but checking one side of the tree, then the other.

```
int check_depth(struct tree *root, int depth)
{
    if (!root) {
        return 0;
    } else if (depth <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return check_depth(root->left,  depth-1) ||
               check_depth(root->right, depth-1);
    }
}
```